# Git creates (duplicates?) large pack files

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a giant git-repo. 45 GB right now. (almost 25 years of development history, migrated multiple times through different VCS and containing a lot of binary files as well)

Most of that is in 1 pack file of about 39.5GB

So far so bad.

Since last week, we've been having issues on our Developer Workstations and our GitLab Runners where suddenly there's no disk space left. What happens is that git seems to create new pack files of about the same size as the biggest pack file, i.e. about 39-40GB. This then happens a couple of times over the course of a (few) day(s) and 500GB Workstation drives and 200GB VM-disk space are quickly eaten up.

I've not found anything looking like this online, only people complaining about 1GB pack files (lol)

GitLab Repo-Check shows a bunch of "invalid reflog entry" errors and "missing tree"/"missing commit", but when I look manually in the history, those commits and hashes are all there.

We also observe that pushing and pulling sometimes takes incredibly long and seems to transfer many GB of data.

Any clues as to what could be causing this? Any ideas as to how to fix it?

Cleaning up the history and shrinking the repo is of course something we should do, but we've had this large a repo for many years without any issues of this kind.

Comment: Could you focus on the operation that creates the pack, and try to get more verbose output of that op? There are at least two env variables which might shed some light: `GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS` and `GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE` - you can find details with `man git`. There are also some maintenance/packing related options in `man git-config` - are they involved here? When repacking, git would necessarily need enough disk space for the input and the output pack for the operation to succeed, so with a 45GB pack, it needs at least another 45GB free for the operation to even be able to complete. If it runs o